# How to add multiple quantities of a single product to cart in product list view page of Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cart, product-list

Currently the functionality is no matter how much quantity you enter in qty field, only one quantity gets added/updated to cart

Comment: which version of magento are you using?

Comment: i am using Magento 2.1

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229978/magento-2-how-to-add-quantity-increment-decrements-button-on-product-details