# Magento 2 : How to Add quantity increment & decrements button on product details page

Tags: magento2, catalog

How to add **increment(plus +)** and **decrements(minus -)** qty button on product detail page?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can implement this with `UI Components`

1) Configure your `requirejs-config.js` to define your `js` module: (`app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Catalog/`).

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'qty-counter': 'Magento_Catalog/js/qty-counter'
        }
    }
};
```

2) Copy and change `template` from `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml` to your theme `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/`

```
...
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Quantity:') ?></span></label>
            <div id="custom-qty" class="control" data-bind="scope: 'qty-counter'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                <script type="text/x-magento-init">
                    {
                        "#custom-qty": {
                            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                                "components": {
                                    "qty-counter": {
                                        "component": "qty-counter",
                                        "config": {
                                            "qty": <?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>,
                                            "dataValidate": <?php echo json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators()) ?>
                                        }
                                    }
                                 }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?></span>
            </button>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

3) Add your `js` module

```
'use strict';

define([
    'ko',
    'uiElement'
], function (ko, Element) {
    return Element.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Catalog/input-counter'
        },

        initObservable: function () {
            this._super()
                .observe('qty');

            return this;
        },

        getDataValidator: function() {
            return JSON.stringify(this.dataValidate);
        },

        decreaseQty: function() {
            var qty;

            if (this.qty() > 1) {
                qty = this.qty() - 1;
            } else {
                qty = 1;
            }

            this.qty(qty);
        },

        increaseQty: function() {
            var qty = this.qty() + 1;

            this.qty(qty);
        }
    });
});
```

4) Add `html` template

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group__addon">
        <button click="decreaseQty" class="input-group__button input-group__button--decrease">
            <span class="input-group__icon input-group__icon--decrease"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
    <input data-bind="value: qty(), attr: {'data-validate': getDataValidator(), 'title': $t('Qty')}"
           type="number"
           name="qty"
           id="qty"
           maxlength="12"
           class="input-group__input" />
    <span class="input-group__addon">
        <button click="increaseQty" class="input-group__button input-group__button--increase">
            <span class="input-group__icon input-group__icon--increase"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Good solution, which generally works for me. But I have a problem with the validation (min, max). I have to modify this validation within my block class (hence in php), which works. But on the frontend, the validation-function `validate-item-quantity` is not triggered.

Comment: At which path should I add the html template? @Volodymyr Lisniak

Answer (score 1):

You can add Quantity Increment and Decrement Button in Magento 2 with KnockoutJS. Create a custom module:

**Configure Module**

Configure your module by creating a `module.xml` file in `app/code/Magenticians/Mymodule/etc.`Add the following code in it:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Magenticians_Mymodule" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

Go to `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view` from the root directory of your store and copy `addtocart.phtml` to your own module `app/code /Magenticians/Mymodule/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view. The addtocart.phtml` file will looks like this:

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class="box-tocart">
   <div class="fieldset">
       <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
       <div class="field qty">
           <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>
           <div class="control">
               <input type="number"
                      name="qty"
                      id="qty"
                      maxlength="12"
                      value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                      title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"
                      data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                      />
           </div>
       </div>
       <?php endif; ?>
       <div class="actions">
           <button type="submit"
                   title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?>"
                   class="action primary tocart"
                   id="product-addtocart-button">
               <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?></span>
           </button>
           <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
   {
       "#product_addtocart_form": {
           "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
               "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
           }
       }
   }
</script>
<?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
   {
       "#product_addtocart_form": {
           "catalogAddToCart": {
               "bindSubmit": false
           }
       }
   }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Follow this [tutorial](https://magenticians.com/quantity-increment-decrement-magento-2/)

Comment: thanks, i don't want to create new module.

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple solution that involves 1 template to be changed and a mixin to be created with 4 lines of jQuery

the mixin js code is:

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (addToCart) {
        $('#minusQty').click(function () {
            $('#qty').val(parseInt($('#qty').val())-1);
        });

        $('#addQty').click(function () {
            $('#qty').val(parseInt($('#qty').val())+1);
        });

        return addToCart;
    }
});
```

and the template to edit is product/view/addtocart.phtml

I have an example at: https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/productdetailqtywidget

Comment: Thanks, As i mentioned in above comment i don't want to add any external module or widget in my code. i want to build this functionality within code.