# How to add ajax increment and decrement button in minicart magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, ajax, magento2.3.0, magento2.3.1

I have follow many article but i don't get proper answer please help me, provide me step by step.

Comment: Try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229978/magento-2-how-to-add-quantity-increment-decrements-button-on-product-details

Answer (score 1):

Please check with below url for increment or decrement working.

[Add Ajax Quantity Increment and Decrement Button on mini cart in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/247176/add-ajax-quantity-increment-and-decrement-button-on-mini-cart-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use for ajax increment and decrement button in minicart Magento 2.3.1. Download below module and use it.

[Add ajax increment and decrement button in minicart magento2](https://github.com/kirtinariya1/MinicartAjaxQtyIncrementDecrement)